# How to debug a array data in CakePHP?

Tags: cakephp

This is my query:

```
    $this->loadModel("Recipe");
    $responses = $this->Response->find("all");
```

How would I display results of responses, so I can chech its content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to debug it by:

```
debug($responses);
```

or:

```
print_r($responses);
```

And it will print its values.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this code:
pr($responses);
```